# What causes fizz?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bubbles

When you go to a soda fountain and pour some soda into your cup, frothy fizz is generated at the top of the cup. What causes this? Obviously has something to do with carbonation, but when my cup is just sitting , there is no fizz. Is it generated by the crash of the soda into the cup?

How could I stop it? By slowing the rate at which it falls? Spinning the liquid on the way down? Changing the material of the cup?

Comment: Might [chemistry.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever watched as someone pours beer into a glass?  Pouring it straight down produces a big head.  Tilting the glass over and allowing the beer to run gently down the side of the glass greatly reduces the size of the head.  The less splash, the less foam.

Before the bottle (or keg) is opened the beer (or soda) is under pressure and the liquid and air above are in equilibrium as regards the amount of $CO_2$ in the air and dissolved in the liquid.  When the pressure is released by opening the container, the $CO_2$ is supersaturated.  Splashing the liquid hastens the return to equilibrium so your "crash of the soda into the cup" hypothesis is correct.  When the glass is just sitting there, the surface tension resists the gas going out of solution and forming bubbles.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! "Splashing the liquid hastens the return to equilibrium" - could you explain this? Why? What would reduce the splash?

Comment: When the liquid splashes the surface tension is broken and gas can more easily escape (forming bubbles). Splashing is reduced when the liquid has less kinetic energy as it reaches the bottom of the glass. Also smoother wall reduces splashing since the flow is more lamilar.